# Let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb R$ differentiable s.t $f^{'}(x) \ge 0$ in $(a,b)$ and $f^{'} = 0$ only in one coordinate. Prove $f$ is strictly increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, continuity

**I actually looked pretty hard for this proof and couldn't find it. Also I feel like my proof isn't very good, I lay a lot of basic groundwork but I feel the logic and the deduction is far from perfect and so I'd love some feedback.**

Here it goes:

We have $f^{'}(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ and $f^{'}(x) = 0$ only once.

Assume $f^{'}(x) = 0$ for some $x_0 \in (a,b)$ s.t $f^{'}(x_0) = 0$.

Let us mark $I_1 = (a,x_0)$ and $I_2 = (x_0,b)$. We have $f^{'}(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \in I_1$ or $I_2$ and from theorem we saw in the lecture this implies $f$ is injective in $I_1$ and $I_2$.

From datum $f(x)$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ we have $f(x)$ continuous in $(a,b)$.

We know the image of a function over some interval is an interval by itself and so let's mark $f(I_1) = I_3$ and $f(I_2) = I_4$.

**This is the part I feel like the proof is losing ground**

From the continuity of $f$ we have $f(x_0) \notin I_3$ or $I_4$.

Notice $\forall x \in I_1$ or $I_2$ we have $f^{'}(x) \gt 0$ which implies $f(x)$ is strictly increasing in $I_1$ and $I_2$.

Also we have $lim_{x \to x_0^{+}}f(x) = lim_{x \to x_0^{-}}f(x)$ and so for all $x_1 \in I_1$ and $x_2 \in I_2$ $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.

All in all we can deduce $f$ is injective in $(a,b) \implies$ $f(x)$ is strictly increasing in $(a,b)$ as needed.

Comment: Hint: Suppose there's an $x_1 \in I_1$ with $f(x_1) \leq f(x_0)$. Use the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: If you are familiar with the mean value theorem, the argument is a one liner: for any $x,y$ in the interval $(a, b)$ there is $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $$f(y)-f(y)=f'(\xi)(y-x)$$ The signage of the increments $f(y)-f(x)$ is now easy to determine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to prove theorems like this is by use of the mean value theorem, with some argument similar to the following. First, we note that for $f$ to be strictly increasing on $(a,b)$ is that whenever we have $x, y \in (a,b)$ where $x < y$, then $f(x) < f(y)$. Let for this sake $x, y \in (a,b), x < y$. We will now consider the interval $[x,y]$.

Of course, $f$ is continuous on $[x,y]$ and differentiable on $(x,y)$. Thus there exists some point $c \in (x,y)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x}$. If this point has $f'(c)$ greater than zero, it follows $f(y) - f(x) > 0 \Leftrightarrow f(y) > f(x)$. All that is left to consider then is that this is the exclusive point at which the derivative is exactly zero (in essence, by contradiction). For this case, we consider the partition of the interval into $[x, c]$, $[c, y]$. As we have then established the derivative is positive on the resultant open intervals then, it is $f(c) > f(x)$ and $f(y) > f(c)$, and thus $f(y) > f(x)$, the desired result.

I haven't read over the entirety of your proof, but it is perhaps evoking unnecessary details for proving this.

Comment: Sounds like a much better and more conclusive approach. Thank you I appreciate it.

Comment: "there exists some point $c \in (x,y)$ such that $c = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x}$." Where did you get this from? Did you mean $f'(c)$ instead of  $c$? Also where is the contradiction you were talking about?

Comment: Edited to reflect the typo $f'(c) \Leftrightarrow c$. The contradiction emerges from the fact that if we had the $c$ implied by the mean value theorem has $f'(c) = 0$, we can contradict this by splitting the interval into two where the derivative is assuredly positive, and thus we can transitively derive $f(y) > f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f'(x)$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, we have $f(r)-f(l)=\int_l^rf'(x)dx(a<l<r<b)$.

Then, if $f(r)-f(l)=\int_l^rf'(x)dx=0$, we can derive $f(x)=0, \text{ a.e. }x\in [l,r] $

Consider the theorem below:

> If $F$ is increasing and continuous, then $F'$ exists almost
> everywhere. Moreover $F'$ is measurable, non-negative, and $$ \int_a^bF'(x)dx\leq F(b)-F(a) $$

Then, the continuity of the $f'(x)$ is no longer needed. We can conclude that if on any $[l,r] \subset (a,b)$, $f(x)$ is not almost everywhere equal to $0$, then $f(x)$ is strictly increasing.